# How can I pad an fstring with dictionary values in

Tags: python, dictionary, padding, f-string

I can use fstring with a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'foo': 'py', 'bar': 'thon'}
print(f"I am using {mydict['foo']}{mydict['bar']}")
> I am using python
```

I can also pad strings:

```
f"{'Foo': <16} Bar"
>'Foo              Bar'
```

I want to be able to pad a string that's coming from my dictionary inside my fstring.

I have tried:

```
f"{{mydict['foo']}: <16} {mydict['bar']}"
```

The error here is:

> File "", line 1
> SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed

Is this possible or do I have to add the padded string to my dictionary first before using?

Comment: `f"{mydict['foo']: <16} {mydict['bar']}"`…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the inner {} is superfluous:

```
mydict = {'foo': 'py', 'bar': 'thon'}
f"{mydict['foo']: <16} {mydict['bar']}"
```

works.